# What does >& mean here?

Tags: linux, bash

I have C code, that has been compiled. Then I have to execute from command line

```
../../../PStomo_eq665/pstomo_eq par=syn.par >& log.syn
```

What does `>&` mean in this context? Both files `syn.par` and `log.syn` contain parameters for `pstomo_eq`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Redirect stderr and stdout

`>&` is equivalent to `&>` and redirects both standard **error** and standard **output**.

From the bash [man](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections) page:

> There are two formats for redirecting standard output and standard
>   error:
>
> `&>word`
>
> and
>
> `>&word`
>
> Of the two forms, the first is preferred.  This is semantically
>   equivalent to:
>
> `>word 2>&1`

In your question, *stderr* and *stdout* are redirected to `log.syn`