# What does >& means in the following code snippet

Tags: shell

```
/bin/perl run_job.pl $run_str >& abc.txt
```

I know it is a redirection. But I want to know the difference between > and >& .

Comment: It is nopt perl related, because the Redirect is in the call on a shell

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34900604/what-does-mean-here/34900808

Answer (score 0):

see https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html

> You may also, in the Bourne shell tradition, specify an EXPR beginning
>   with >&, in which case the rest of the string is interpreted as the
>   name of a filehandle (or file descriptor, if numeric) to be duped (as
>   in dup(2)) and opened.

More informations you can also get [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176216/redirection-differences-between-and-21)

> Only >& works in csh or tcsh

Answer (score 0):

Shell provides the capability to separate out standard output and error output of a command execution. You can separate out the two output streams using > for standard out and 2> for error output.

```
./shellscript.sh > stdout.txt 2> errorout.txt
```

You can redirect both of these values to a single file if that is desired using &> or >&. Therefore, the standard output and error output of **run_job.pl** will get redirected to **abc.txt**.